# MOSFET P type voltage drop high side

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to learn about MOSFETs and I went into the problem of voltage drops across it I have tried to search the web for answers and I think I have the answer. Please tell me if my assumption is wrong. *[image: emphasized text]*

Let’s say I used this MOSFET IRF9540NPBF is it safe to say that if I want to have almost 1 voltage drop across source-drain its going to conduct 9 A assuming my Vgs is around 8 V m? Source voltage is 8.4 V and gate is grounded.

Comment: About that, yes.

Comment: Note that those graphs represent _typical_ numbers, not worst-case. If you want guarantees, you want worst-case numbers (e.g. Rdson _max_ @ -8Vgs). Or derate significantly.

Comment: If i cant find that specific voltage in the tables, should i go for the max RDS (on) ,let's say at 4.5 v  for safety or , do i look in the normalized chart for the specific Amps i need ?. Or would they both give around the same answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *is it safe to say that if I want to have almost 1 voltage drop across
> source-drain its going to conduct 9 A assuming my Vgs is around 8 V*

A typical device will start at around 8 amps then, as it warms, the current will reduce. If it was allowed to keep warming (i.e. you had insufficient heatsinking) you will find that the current could drop to around 4 amps when the internal junction of the MOSFET reached 175° C: -

[image]

Modified image from [here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf9540npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535611cfa21dc8&redirId=112299).

Comment: Thanks, I was getting lost , I first thought they would work like connecting a line but it seems if you pick poorly you will have a hogh voltage drop